# How to limit row number in pagination with select option

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have a page is already pagination. But now i want to implement new feature:
when we select number of rows in select box. The webpage will be show matching data. I tried it with ajax. A limit variable has been send, but controller can not get it to process. Can anyone help me!

[here is sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkB8c.png)

html code:

```
<form method="post">
<select name="select_limit" id="select_limit">
     <option value="10">10</option>
     <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
</form>
```

ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select_limit').change(function() {
        var limit = $("#select_limit option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            cache:false,
            url:"<?php //link to controller ?>",
            //send data
            data:{'limit': limit},
            });
    });
});
```

and in controller, I get a limit variable the same normal code:

```
$limit = $_POST['select_limit'];
```

Comment: Show your PHP and jQuery code here

Comment: @DeepKakkar
can you help me, plz?

Comment: you need to use this limit in your sql query.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh
I know, but i can not get $limit for limit it in sql query. pagination with static $limit is ok. but now is dynamic$limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need not to use ajax, you can try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#select_limit').change(function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});

// use get method, and form action should be same url like pagination link 
<form method="get">
  <select name="select_limit" id="select_limit">
     <option value="10" <?php echo $limit == 10 ? 'selected' : ''?>>10</option>
     <option value="100" <?php echo $limit == 100 ? 'selected' : ''?>>100</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

this sloution will refresh the page.

> edit

==================================================================

and add the `&limit=<?php echo $limit?>` to the link like:

```
 <li class="<?php  if($crr_page=$i) echo 'active' ?>">
      <a href="<?php echo $this->url->get('dashboard/list-user') ?>?page=<?php echo $i ; ?>&txt_keyword=<?php echo $keyword; ?>&limit=<?php echo $limit?>"><?php  echo $i  ?></a>
 </li>
```

Comment: This will only refresh the page if the php script that the form links to redirects him to the page after whatever his script is doing. Normally you will just go to the url defined in `action`.

Comment: @Alex
that's good ideal. it's working. but only page 1. When I change to another page. It return 10 row in 1 page. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: thanks @AlexLooksSoSad, but It's the same as my current code, and you now, at another page, 10 row in 1 page :(. I think this problem is sever can not keep <code> $limit<code> when we change page

Comment: yes, here is my pagination code:
http://notepad.cc/share/s3gexOG3ol
 $this->url->get('dashboard/list-user')  is link to my controller

Comment: @yanndinh  see my newest answer

Comment: What a great solution! Why me can not think. Thankyou so much @AlexLooksSoSad. But I dont enough reputation to vote up or move the discussion to chat. big big thank for you

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `data:{'limit': limit},` and you try to get `$_POST['select_limit'];` so you are trying to get a POST value that you are not sending. Try `$_POST['limit'];`

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code on my webserver with `$_POST['limit'];` and it is working correctly. Do you get any error messages either from the JavaScript console or your php script?

Comment: No error message from script, only can not get $limit in controller.